# matrix with variable and their rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

$M = \pmatrix{1 + p& 0& 0& p\\p& 2p& 1 + 3p& p\\2p& 0& 0& 0\\0& 4p& 0& 2p\\p& 2p& 3p& p}$
has rank $4$ for for a variable $p\in\mathbb{C} \text{ or }\mathbb{R}$, does this mean: for any complex number $p$ the columns are linearly independent set of vectors in $\mathbb{C}^5 \text { or }\mathbb{R}^5$?

And, regarding the assurance of its rank $4$, I put it in Matlab and asked rank($M$), and it gives result $4$

Comment: Rank 4 here  means columns make four linearly independent vectors; but they are in a 5-dimensional vector space; so cannot form a basis.

Comment: $M$ has rank $4$ if $p\neq 0$.

Comment: @PVanchinathan oops! sorry , exactly, thank you

Comment: @i707107 why $p\ne 0$?

Comment: $p=0$, makes last 3 rows identically zero. So rank has to be 2 or less.

Comment: When $p=0$, then $M$ has two columns of all zeros.

Comment: @PVanchinathan so here my doubts come!  what is the definition of a rank of a matrix with variable?

Comment: @PVanchinathan so far I know rank must be unique, but here when we change values of $p$, rank is getting changed

Comment: It depends: if you think of it as matrix over the polynomial ring with  $p$ an indeterminate, determinant being invertible element of that that rings makes it non-singular. A determinant can be non-zero as a polynomial, but zero for specific substitutions. So rank will fall for those substitutions, but regarded as matrix over constant field.

Comment: I don't understand, how can we talk about determinant of a $5\times 4$ matrix?

Comment: The first, third, fourth, and fifth rows of $M$ form a square matrix $B$ whose determinant is $-24 p^4$. So if $p\neq 0$ then rank(B)=4 and therefore rank(M)=4. If $p=0$, rank(M)=2

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is the second time you created basis tag (see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/10/21) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/11/4).) The result of discussion of this tag on meta was that this is not a good tag, please have a look at the [relevant post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21091/can-we-delete-the-basis-tag). In general, unless you are sure that the tag you want to create is really necessary, it is good to ask on meta first (or search whether the tag has already been discussed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p=0$, the last column is equal to zero, so in this case rank is clearly at most $3$.

Let us have a look on the case $p\ne0$. A rather standard method to find [matrix rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) is to use [elementary row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_row_operations) and/or elementary column operations. Notice that since we assume that $p\ne0$, we are allowed to divide by $p$.

$\begin{pmatrix}
1+p& 0 & 0  & p\\
 p &2p &1+3p& p\\
2p & 0 & 0  & 0\\
 0 &4p & 0  &2p\\
 p &2p &3p  & p
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1+p& 0 & 0  & p\\
 p &2p &1+3p& p\\
 2 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
 0 & 4 & 0  & 2\\
 1 & 2 & 3  & 1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
1+p& 0 & 0  & p\\
 p &2p &1+3p& p\\
 0 & 4 & 0  & 2\\
 1 & 2 & 3  & 1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0  & p\\
 0 &2p &1+3p& p\\
 0 & 2 & 0  & 1\\
 0 & 2 & 3  & 1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0  & 1\\
 0 & 0 &1+3p& 0\\
 0 & 2 & 0  & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 3  & 0
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
 0 & 2 & 0  & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 3  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0  & 1\\
 0 & 0 &1+3p& 0
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
 0 & 2 & 0  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0  & 1\\
 0 & 0 &1+3p& 0
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0  & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$

We see that the rank (in the case $p\ne0$) is indeed equal to $4$.

And to answer your additional question: Yes, this means that for $p\ne0$ the columns are linearly independent.